# Check if the item in the List is incremental and not redundant

Tags: c#, list, linq

I need to retain all the list that are redundant and not incremental. But my code so far is for the items that are redundant only

```
_lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "1",
                        Pdf = "PDF1"
                    });

                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "1",
                        Pdf = "PDF1"
                    });

                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "1",
                        Pdf = "PDF2"
                    });


                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "2",
                        Pdf = "PDF2"
                    });

                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "3",
                        Pdf = "PDF2"
                    });


                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "1",
                        Pdf = "PDF3"
                    });

                    _lst.Add(new MSheetValue
                    {
                        Column = 1,
                        Line = "3",
                        Pdf = "PDF3"
                    });
```

Here is my code

```
var result = _lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.Line, x.Pdf })
               .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any()).ToList();
```

and the result is

```
Column = 1,
Line = "1",
Pdf = "PDF1"
```

But i also need the list that are not incremental

so i also need this

```
Column = 1,
Line = "1",
Pdf = "PDF3"


Column = 1,
Line = "3",
Pdf = "PDF3"
```

How can i solve it. I tried searching for a solution and test what i've found but i can't solve it. it doesn't return what i expected

Comment: Explain your not incremental point of view

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinctItems = _lst.Distinct();
```

To match on only some of the properties, create a custom equality comparer, e.g.:

```
class DistinctItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item> {

public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) {
    return x.Column == y.Column &&
        x.Line == y.Line &&
        x.Pdf == y.Pdf;
}

public int GetHashCode(Item obj) {
    return obj.Column.GetHashCode() ^
        obj.Line.GetHashCode() ^        
        obj.Pdf.GetHashCode();
}
```

}

Then use it like this:

```
var distinctItems = _lst.Distinct(new DistinctItemComparer());
```

Or try it:

```
var distinctItems = _lst.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

using zip to get the adjacent items and then comparing the adjacent items and selecting the items that are not adjacent may do the trick.  This example is a little oversimplified as you may want to compare the field with Pdfs as well.  The Union adds the duplicates to the non-adjacents.

```
return _lst.Zip(_lst.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { a, b})
.Where(w => w.b.Line != w.a.Line + 1)
.Select(w => w.b)

.Union(_lst.GroupBy(x => new { x.Line, x.Pdf })
           .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any()).ToList()
           .SelectMany(s => s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some handy extension methods:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combine) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prevkv;
                    prevkv = (combine(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prevkv;
            }
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupByWhile<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> test, Func<T, TRes> result) =>
        src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => test(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1).GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => result(kvp.Value));

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupBySequential<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, int> SeqNum, Func<T, TRes> result) =>
        src.GroupByWhile((prev, cur) => SeqNum(prev) + 1 == SeqNum(cur), result);
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupBySequential<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, int> SeqNum) => src.GroupBySequential(SeqNum, e => e);

    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keyFun, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null) {
        var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var e in src)
            if (seenKeys.Add(keyFun(e)))
                yield return e;
    }

    public static int ToInteger(this string s) => Convert.ToInt32(s);
}
```

`ScanPair` is a variation of my APL inspired `Scan` operator (which is like `Aggregate` only returns the intermediate results). I discovered I was doing a lot of `Scan` with tuples to carry the original information, so `ScanPair` combines the intermediate results with the original values.

Using `ScanPair`, `GroupByWhile` runs a test on each element and groups while the test is true.
Using `GroupByWhile`, `GroupBySequential` groups when each elements sequence number is sequential.

`DistinctBy` returns the distinct objects based on a key selection function. I cheat and use this rather than create an `IEqualityComparer` for `MSheetValue`.

Finally, `ToInteger` is just a handy extension for reading flow.

With these extension methods, processing the `_lst` is relatively straightforward:

```
var nonSeq = _lst.GroupBy(m => m.Pdf) // need to test each Pdf
                 .Select(mg => mg.GroupBySequential(m => m.Line.ToInteger())) // get the sequential groups
                 .Where(mg => mg.Count() > 1) // keep the ones with non-sequential lines
                 // parse each non-sequential group into just the unique entries and flatten
                 .Select(mg => mg.SelectMany(m => m).DistinctBy(m => new { m.Column, m.Line, m.Pdf }));
```